# "Disambiguieren" vs. "Desambiguieren"

Tags: etymology, prefix

Is *desambiguieren* a correct word form in German language (instead of *disambiguieren*)? Duden does not know this form but I'm pretty sure that I've seen it in scientific papers, long ago. I'm interested in answers with etymological backgrounds.

Comment: see also https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dis_ and https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/des__Verneinung

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven’t been able to find the form with *des-* in Grimm, Duden or DWDS. The form with *-dis* is found in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/disambiguieren) and [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/disambiguieren) and the associated noun has a German [Wikipedia page](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disambiguierung). Furthermore, my spellcheck on iPad (German, Germany) doesn’t accept *desambiguieren* and suggests *disambiguieren* as a replacement:
[image]

Before digging into this I was inclined to believe that *desambiguieren* and its associated noun never became a standard scientific term in German.  However, [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Disambiguation%2CDesambiguation%2Cdisambiguieren%2Cdesambiguieren&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDisambiguation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisambiguieren%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesambiguieren%3B%2Cc0) found some occurrences of *desambiguieren*:
[image]
and I think it is obvious from results such as [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22desambiguieren%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1977,cd_max:1994&lr=lang_de&gws_rd=ssl) that *desambiguieren* has appeared in serious scientific publications.

> As *desambiguieren* is a technical term and has appeared in serious scientific publications, it is hard to argue  it‘s *incorrect*; but *disambiguieren* currently fulfils more criteria of a *standard word*. We should remember we are talking of specialised scientific vocabulary. Such words tend to be rare and only slowly enter popular dictionaries.

As links in the comments have already shown you, German words with *des-* tend to derive from French. Indeed *des-* is the french rendition of Latin *dis-*. A french pendant certainly exists in the form of [*désambiguïser*](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9sambigu%C3%AFser). As knowledge of both Latin and French arguably enjoyed more prestige in Germany in the past, it is hard to formulate conjectures as to the evolution of the relative frequency of *disambiguieren* and *desambiguieren*. Ngram suggests that *disambiguieren* appeared slightly earlier and has always remained more popular.

I very much suspect that a group of scientists was influenced in their choice by the [work of Roland Barthes on the subject](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disambiguierung#Beispiele_f%C3%BCr_Mehrdeutigkeiten). Roland Barthes wrote in French. As you can see in the aforementioned Wikipedia article, the German version of his work, »Die große Familie der Menschen« appeared in 1964, at about the time when the words in question appear in ngram data! I have, however, not been able to find out whether there were earlier German editions! Perhaps everything is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

*Schulz/Basler et al.*, Deutsches Fremdwörterbuch, vol. 1 (a-Präfixe - Antike), 2nd ed. 1995, consider *desambiguieren* an occasional variant of *disambiguieren*:

> Anfang 19. Jh. [...] das aus gleichbed. lat. *ambigere* (s. o.)
>   entlehnte, meist gebuchte und heute veraltete Verb **ambigieren**
>   'zweifeln, unschlüssig sein' (zu b); in neuerer Zeit von der
>   Sprachwissenschaft wieder aufgenommen in der latinisierenden
>   Präfixbildung **disambiguieren** V. trans, 'die Ambiguität eines
>   sprachlichen Ausdrucks durch Zuordnung mehrerer syntaktischer
>   Strukturen oder semantischer Interpretationen aufheben, einen
>   sprachlichen Ausdruck eindeutig machen, vereindeutigen,
>   monosemieren', vereinzelt auch in der Nebenform *desambiguieren*; dazu
>   das häufiger als das Verb belegte Verbalsubst. **Disambiguierung** E
>   (-; -en), vereinzelt auch die Nebenformen *Desambiguierung* und
>   *Entambiguisierung* (zu a).

Comment: +1 für‘s „Wissen wo man nachguckt“ ;)